# Firebase does not recognize document path

Tags: node.js, firebase

So I have the following request with which I am trying to do the following:

- Look for a collection with the name 'questionnaires'
- Look at a specific document with id, given by the parameter of the function
- Take the reference of a collection 'questions' within this document

```
public async getQuestionnaire(
    questionnaireId: string,
  ): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.CollectionReference<DocumentData>> {
    const questionsCollection = await getFirestore().collection(
      'questionnaires/{questionnaireId}/questions/',
    );

    return questionsCollection;
  }
```

I tried both by obtaining the reference in one line or seperating it the following way:

```
public async getQuestionnaire(
    questionnaireId: string,
  ): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.CollectionReference<DocumentData>> {
    const questionnairesCollection =
      getFirestore().collection('questionnaires');

    const desiredQuestionnaire = questionnairesCollection.doc(questionnaireId);

    const questions = desiredQuestionnaire.collection('questions');
    return questions;
  }
```

The method is called from the following get request handler:

```
@Get('/firebase/questionnaire/:questionnaireId')
  @OpenAPI({ summary: 'Return a questionnaire' })
  async getQuestionnaire(@Param('questionnaireId') questionnaireId: string) {
    const questionsRef = await this.firebaseService.getQuestionnaire(
      questionnaireId,
    );
    return { data: questionsRef };
  }
```

The interesting thing is that if I print out the reference, I get exactly what I want. However when I try to return it, I get the following error:

```
[GET] /firebase/questionnaire/3iz5K3hsVvaFBwkyzd57 >> StatusCode:: 500, 
      Message:: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is exactly the goal of your code? It is not clear if you want to get a `QuerySnapshot`, a `DocumentSnapshot` (i.e. the field values of the document) or just a `CollectionReference`. If you want to get the field values you need to call the asynchronous `get()` method on a `DocumentReference`. So far you only define Collection or Document references (In `return { data:  questionsRef };`, `questionsRef` is a `CollectionReference`), and the corresponding methods are not asynchronous. Also, at **which exact line** do you get the error mentioned at the end of your question.

Comment: Thank you for the response Renaud. The goal of my code is to obtain the data in the questions collection. I am aware that I only have a collection reference, however no matter the output (collection reference or QuerySnapshot), I get the error when I execute the get request on the server i run locally. I ran the debugger and the error occurs at the return statement in the `getQuestionnaire` function.

Comment: What do you mean by "the get request"? Calling `getQuestionnaire`or the Firestore `get()` method? I don't see any `documentPath`variable in your code so it is complicated to help you.

Comment: Above the getQuestionnaire method you can see that there is a @Get annotation. By executing the get request I literally mean typing `http://localhost:3001/firebase/questionnaire/3iz5K3hsVvaFBwkyzd57` in the browser. That is what I can not understand, because for example when I try to print out the query snapshot, everything is printed as it should be. But when the return line is executed I receive the error and it is really confusing since there is no documentPath as you said.

Comment: O, gotcha :-) Can you debug the `getQuestionnaire` function to see if one of the variable there is empty? Also note that you don't return a QuerySnapshot in your code, only CollectionReferences. See my first comment.

Comment: So I debugged it, there are none variables which are empty. I decided to solve the issue a different way, instead of returning a QuerySnapshot, I took the information I need and returned it as a custom object. Thank you for the assistance though, I appreciate it a lot :)